How to use the LEN function in Excel so it counts all characters (including spaces, puntcuation, etc?)
The result is incorrect when trying to count the number of characters in Excel. When trying to do the same in Google Spreadsheets it works ok.
Wrote the same formula for the same data - but different response:
In Excel, the output is 15; in Spreadsheets, it's 19 - the correct answer is 19.


In Excel, dates are integers and times are decimals. Actually, today is 45490 for Excel. And 45490.5 would be 17th July 2024 12:00:00 PM So in Excel LEN is returning the characters of the numeric value of the date. Remember: Excel and Google Sheets are not the same even if they've been developed for the same

In case of Excel you may use =LEN(TEXT(C2,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")) if C2 cell value is true date.

Just to be clear, Excel uses a serial number to represent the date which can then be formatted into any "standard" date format (month, day, year or day, month, year)
